# Error in an XML file reported and aborting build

Tags: android

When i edited the res/layout/main.xml and tried to re-run the application build. the following error message appears:

```
[2011-05-28 08:56:04 - MyWebApps1] res\layout\main.xml:0: error: Resource entry main is already defined.
[2011-05-28 08:56:04 - MyWebApps1] res\layout\main.out.xml:0: Originally defined here.
[2011-05-28 08:56:04 - MyWebApps1] C:\Users\Toshiba\Documents\android\MyWebApps1\res\layout\main.out.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: no element found
[2011-05-28 08:56:07 - MyWebApps1] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
```

the main.xml file was edited correctly. No syntax error. Anyone has idea?

Answer (score 6):

You pressed F11 to run the app but while being on the main.xml and due to your Eclipse configuration it ran the xml file, generating the .out.xml. Just delete it.

Comment: I can't up vote this enough. This cost me two hours as the problem would go away and then come back. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You need to delete the **main.out.xml** in your `res/layout/` , and then clean your project.
If you work on Eclipse IDE , do like this : Project ==> Clean ==> check your project , and press OK.

Comment: it is working now. I need to delete main.out.xml, clean the project and relaunch Eclipse IDE

Comment: i said , delete the file Main.OUT.xml ; and not the main.xml ; and then clean your project :)

Comment: Glad to hear it :), vote the question if it resolve the problem

Answer (score 2):

You must open "MainActivity.java" file, and try run again

Answer (score 2):

Stop deleting your .out.xml!

While it's true that will "fix" your issue it will cause other issues, especially if you're designing and working on the UI with the 'graphical layout' tab in Eclipse. What's happening is that you're run configuration is messed up, you go to run it but it's trying to run .out.xml so it fails. The solution is not to start deleting files.

Click to the right of your green circle "run" button to bring down the options list and select "Run Configurations." Configure one for an emulated Android device. When you run the code use this custom configured run. Also, run from your main java file.